# setting up a value for a variable name in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and converting my Web page from JSP to Thymeleaf. I have a strut tag like this:

```
<c:set var="someVariable" value="${someValue}"/>
```

That variable can be used anywhere in JSP. Is there any such alternatives for this in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can use [local variables](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables).

Declare an HTML element with a `th:with` attribute. For example

```
<div th:with="someVariable=${someValue}">
```

The documentation states

> When `th:with` is processed, that `[someVariable]` variable is created as a
>   local variable and added to the variables map coming from the context,
>   so that it is as available for evaluation as any other variables
>   declared in the context from the beginning, **but only within the bounds
>   of the containing  tag.**

Answer (score 61):

Just a note, if you wish to assign more than one variable, separate them with a comma :

```
<div th:with="someVariable=${someValue},anotherVariable=${anotherValue}">
```

See the third example : [Local Variable section of Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables)

Answer (score 26):

1. declare with `th:with="varName=${'str'}`
2. ref with in src `th:src="@{${varName}}"`
3. in more detail:

```html
<head th:with="component =${'/static/component'}, bizJs = ${'/static/js/biz'}">
    <span th:text="${component}"></span>
    <script th:src="@{(${component})}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{${bizJs} + '/static/js'}"></script>
</head>
```