# Looping through array Thymeleaf using javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have the array variable (coming from back end) called "products". It has the following structure:
--products
-----special
----------0
---------------id
---------------price
---------------etc.....
----------1
---------------id
---------------price
---------------etc
----------2..etc

I am using thymeleaf. I am trying to loop the "special products" in javascript and trying to use their indexes to get the subdata (id, price, etc..).
I am trying to use a new integer variable called "counter" to access the index. So my code is:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" th:with="setProducts=(${products.special})">
    function LetsSayLoop() {
        var counter = 0;
        //looping through some checkboxes
        $('#checkboxContainer .checkboxesClassName').each(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                //this is working:
                var current_product_price = [[${setProducts[0].price}]];
                //this is also working:
                //var current_product_price = [[${setProducts[1].price}]];
                //etc...

                //this is not working:
                var current_product_price = [[${setProducts[counter].price}]];
                counter++;
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

My IDE (netbeans) is saying that the variable "counter " is not being used. Also the generated Javascritp and HTML ends with the following:
 Any ideas why?

```
var current_product_price =
```

EDIT: Small addition about the loop in javascript:

```
//[[${#lists.size(setProducts)}]] outputs the desired integer;
for (i = 0; i < [[${#lists.size(setProducts)}]]; i++) {
    //this is working:
    console.log([[${setProducts[0].price}]]);
    //this is not:
    console.log([[${setProducts[i].price}]]);
}
```

EDIT: (possible answer?)
I understood that thymeleaf does not recognize local javascript variables in [[]] scope. For example:

```
var current_product_price = [[${setProducts[counter].price}]];
```

the code expects that the variable "counter" is coming from thymeleaf.
I need to do it using indexes, but with local variables it does not work. Can I increment some local js variables to accomplish this? Or is it some other way?

Comment: So the only issue is a warning you see on your IDE? The code is working properly? Could be a bug on the IDE, they have those :P the code seems fine to me.

Comment: Nope, the code is not working. It breaks and the output ends with:
"var current_product_price = " and Thats it. No more code after that

Answer (score 1):

If you change `jquery.each` for a `forEach` it should work. Here one example

```
 function a() {
      var counter =0;
      [1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(e){
              console.log('Element:', e);
              console.log('Counter:', counter++);
      });
 }

 a();
```

Comment: the main idea is that the generated javascript will not show unused data(such as name, id, etc..). This method will probably work, but [1,2,3,4] will be replaced with the actual product full information

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine to me, 
so it should work.

If the only issue is a warning you see on the IDE, I wouldn't worry, it could be a bug.

However you don't need to use a counter, you can use the build-in variable that .each uses:

```
.each(function( index, element ) {
  //Use index instead of counter.
}
```

EDIT:

Ok I think now I understand the issue:

You cannot use javascript variables inside this kind of expression. Break it down into two - first create a js variable from the array, then use [index] like so:

```
function LetsSayLoop() {
    var current_Products = [[${setProducts}]]; //btw not sure about double brackets
    //looping through some checkboxes
    $('#checkboxContainer .checkboxesClassName').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {

            //this should work:
            var current_product_price = current_Products[index];
            //etc...  
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: it sure does work, but the generated javascript has all the ${setProducts} fields which I want not to be shown in the code

Comment: @jondaniels Hmm ok, so you can't create a counter on Thymeleaf ? {

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll post an answer.

Please add this line to the `each` call and show us if counter is in fact available in the `each` scope and updated. Next to that you'll know how many times it is actually called.

```
alert("Counter val: " + counter.toString());
```

Comment: Thats not the issue. The loop breaks after reading the line "var current_product_price = [[${setProducts[counter].price}]];" . I am not being able to use the counter variable. If this variable is replaced by a Thymeleaf variable it is ok, but I cannot evaluate the thymeleaf variable

Comment: Could it be a problem with the setProducts[] array? Output it's size and let us know. I understand this seems redundant, but you leave us with little information and no example to run.

Comment: the size is OK. The thing I managed to discover is that thymeleaf understands that the line: `var current_product_price = [[${setProducts[counter].price}]];` is using the variable counter, that is coming from thymeleaf and i cannot use some local js variable. The question is can I use a local thymeleaf variable and increment it every time?

Comment: This is a different question, update your question statement above and you'll get an answer. I expect it to be no, but I'm not experienced with Thymeleaf. Maybe there is something in their documentation?

Comment: With my limited knowledge:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728660/setting-up-a-value-for-a-variable-name-in-thymeleaf

Comment: I am familiar with this and trying to use it