# Thymeleaf does not display all objects of my iterator

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, thymeleaf

I am studying thymeleaf recently and I need a little help for a college project. Basically I have to apply the iterator pattern design to iterate on a list of objects and then print them on video on my website. I created my own iterator but however when I try to iterate with thymeleaf only the first element of the list is printed, the others are ignored.
The code for my iterator is:

```
public class ConcreteIterator<T> implements MyIterator<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    private int index;

    public ConcreteIterator(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.index = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (hasNext()) {
            T item = list.get(index);
            index++;
            return item;
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("No items left!");
        }
    }
}
```

Il codice thymeleaf è, invece, il seguente:

```
<div th:while="${gameIterator.hasNext()}">
      <div th:text="${gameIterator.getCurrent().getName()}"></div>
      <div th:text="${gameIterator.getCurrent().getDescription()}"></div>
      <th:block th:width="${gameIterator.next()}"></th:block>
</div>
```

I solved it this way and now print the whole list:

```
<div th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(1, size)}">

    <div th:text="${gameIterator.getCurrent().getName()}"></div>
    <div th:text="${gameIterator.getCurrent().getDescription()}"></div>

    <div th:if="${gameIterator.hasNext()}">
        <th:block th:width="${gameIterator.next()}"></th:block>
    </div>

</div>
```

However it is a very forced method and I would like, if I could, to do it with just using the while as in the code above (alternatively I could also use javasccript, but I don’t know how to get the iterator in the javascript script to iterate). Thanks to anyone who will help me or give me a tip!

Comment: Where does `gameIterator` come from?

Comment: By the way, if `hasNext` is false, `next` typically [throws a `NoSuchElementException`, not an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#next()).

Comment: @dan1stiscrying The iterator comes from my controller that communicates with the db postgre taking the game objects and creates the iterator. Then he puts it in the model.

Comment: generally, you might want to return a `Collection`/`Iterable` if possible since these are easier to deal with. However, it's still possible with an `Iterator` but that only allows iterating _once_

Comment: @dan1stiscrying I know but I have to manage it through iterator because it is required by the project. However, I’ve noticed that printing with iterator only prints the first one, but I need to print them all. Is it possible to do it through iterator but with javascript or the output would be the same?

Comment: JavaScript wouldn't really help you since you need to get it in the HTML (or similar) before if you want to access it with JS later so you would likely have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible (if you are using `Iterable`/`Iterator` provided by the JDK and have access to the `Iterable`), try using `th:each` with the `Iterable` instead of directly using the `Iterator`:

```html
<div th:each="current:${gameIterable}">
      <div th:text="${current.getName()}"></div>
      <div th:text="${current.getDescription()}"></div>
</div>
```

However, if this is not possible, you can [use `th:with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20731413/10871900):

```html
<div th:while="${gameIterator.hasNext()}">
    <th:block th:with="current=${gameIterator.next()}">
      <div th:text="${current.getName()}"></div>
      <div th:text="${current.getDescription()}"></div>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

This assigns the value returned by `Iterator#next` to a variable (`current`) and then uses that variable as needed.

If you need to iterate over it multiple times, you might want to put the elements in a `List` which you can then iterate over multiple times. You can do something like this in your controller:

```java
Iterable<YourClass> gameIterable = whateverGetsYourIterable();
List<YourClass> gameList = new ArrayList<>();
gameIterable.forEach(gameList::add);
model.addAttribute("gameList",gameList)
```

and then use `th:each` in your Thymeleaf code.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me. In my iterator I have 5 items but on video only the first one is printed. It’s not an iterator problem because I tried to print with java and print correctly. The problem is when I have to print with thymeleaf.

Comment: Note that you can only use the `Iterator` once. If you want to iterate over it multiple times, you should put it in a `List` (in Java code) or similar (and not iterate over it anywhere else).

Comment: Yes I know. I was looking for a way to use it several times and print all my objects only with the iterator as on java. But I realized that is not possible, thank you very much!